# How to find out items in each partition after repartition in Java Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Java ArrayList with few Integer values. 
I have created a DataSet with the ArrayList.
I used **System.out.println(DF.javaRDD().getNumPartitions());** and it resulted in 1 partition. 
I wanted to divide the data into 3 partitions. so I used repartition().
I want to find out the number of items in each partition after repartition.

In scala it is straight forward.

```
DF.repartition(3).mapPartitions((it) => Iterator(it.length));
```

But the same syntax is not working in Java since the length function is not available in Iterator Interface in Java.

**How should we interpret mappartition function?**

```
mapPartitions(FlatMapFunction<java.util.Iterator<T>,U> f)
```

**What are the parameters that inner function will take and what is its return type?**

```
SparkSession sessn = SparkSession.builder().appName("RDD to DF").master("local").getOrCreate();
        List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
        Dataset<Integer> DF = sessn.createDataset(lst, Encoders.INT());
        System.out.println(DF.javaRDD().getNumPartitions());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```java
   List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
        Dataset<Integer> DF = spark.createDataset(lst, Encoders.INT());
        System.out.println(DF.javaRDD().getNumPartitions());
        MapPartitionsFunction<Integer, Integer> f =
                it -> ImmutableList.of(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(it).asScala().length()).iterator();
        DF.repartition(3).mapPartitions(f,
                Encoders.INT()).show(false);
        /**
         * 2
         * +-----+
         * |value|
         * +-----+
         * |6    |
         * |8    |
         * |6    |
         * +-----+
         */
```

Comment: ImmutableList.of(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(it).asScala().length()).iterator()
Which packages you have imported for ImmutableList and rest others?
mapPartitions(FlatMapFunction<java.util.Iterator<T>,U> f) --> Can you explain the input for the inner function and output from the inner function?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at my end. Do we need to include and jar's from maven repository before we use some of these classes and functions?

Comment: Which classes are causing problems?

Comment: Dataset<Integer> mappartDS = DF.repartition(3).mapPartitions(it->  Arrays.asList(JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(it).length()).iterator(), Encoders.INT()); --> I tweaked your code a bit.   asScala() is not available for some reason in my Java environment. This gives me a DataSet.  I have also written to convert it into javaRDD.
JavaRDD<Integer> mappartRdd = DF.repartition(3).javaRDD().mapPartitions(it->  Arrays.asList(JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(it).length()).iterator()); --> This has created a RDD. How to convert an RDD to DF in JavaSpark?

Comment: `Dataset<Integer> DF = spark.createDataset(rdd, Encoders.INT())`

Comment: Dataset<Integer> DF = spark.createDataset(rdd, Encoders.INT())
This is working only when it is a Plain Raw RDD. It isn't working with JavaRDD.
when we are passing first paramater as JavaRDD then it is expecting Beanclass as the second parameter. I passed org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.class but it is saying the object is not an instance of declaring class.

Comment: Can't you use `javaRdd.rdd()`?

Comment: Dataset<Integer> RDD2DF = sessn.createDataset(JavaRDD.toRDD(mappartRdd), Encoders.INT()); I did convert JavaRDD to Plain RDD using toRDD() and it is perfectly working and creating a DATASET.  The following doesn't seem to work when creating DATAFRAME. sessn.createDataFrame(mappartRdd, beanclass); I gave JavaRDD.class in place of Beanclass. It says object is not an instance of declaring class. I am trying to create a DataFrame in specific using JAVARDD. so what will be the right parameter for Beanclass?

Comment: use same ` Encoders.INT()`. feel free to accept and upvote if the answer helps you.

Comment: sessn.createDataFrame(mappartRdd,  Encoders.INT()); --> This is throwing the following error. 

The method createDataFrame(RDD<A>, TypeTags.TypeTag<A>) in the type SparkSession is not applicable for the arguments (JavaRDD<Integer>, Encoder<Integer>)
There are many overloaded functions for createDataFrame(). One of which is accepting JavaRDD as first param and Class as 2nd param. Other function is acceptiong JavaRDD as first param and Beanclass as 2nd param. The 2nd param is what is creating the problem. I am unsure of what to specify.
BTW I did upvote your answer.

Comment: answered to your follow up question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349224